# apply function to array then append result to the array without loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reduce

I have an array `a` and a list `b`.
I want to sum values in `a` indexed by values in `b` then append it to `a`.

For example, `a[[1,2]] = 3 + 4 = 7` then append 7 to `a`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,5,6])
b = [[1,2], [3,4]]

for positions in b:
    tmp = a[positions].sum()
    a = np.append(a, tmp)

a 
array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 11])
```

Could I use reduce instead of a loop?

Comment: `reduce` isn't the way to go here. You could probably a way to do this using `reduce`, but there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
c = np.hstack((a, a[np.r_[b]].sum(1)))

print(c)

array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 11])
```

`numpy.append`, especially in a loop, is inefficient and not recommended. To see what's happening here, note that [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) takes an array as an input and stacks results along the first axis:

```
print(a[np.r_[b]])

array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

We then need only sum along axis 1, and stack with the original array.

Comment: this does not work if elements in b have different length.`array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)`

Answer (score 0):

Can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
>>> np.concatenate([a, [a[pos].sum() for pos in b]])
array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 11])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce, per the documentation,

> Appl[ies] function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).

The salient parts are that reduce operates on pairs of inputs within the list, in sequence, and reduces the list to a single number.

Your example code only shows `positions` in sequence, but if that's not the case, reduce would be a bad option. Additionally, since you want to add multiple values to the original list (7 and 11), you'd have to use the `reduce` operation multiple times since each time only results in a single output.

You could consider instead using a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,5,6])
b = [[1,2], [3,4]]
np.append(a, [a[positions].sum() for positions in b])

a 
array([ 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 11])
```